# Oracle client versions

Tags: oracle, client, version

we are currently running a 10.2.0.1 clients against a 11g database
We would like to update to a more recent version.
Our VB6 applications use oo4o and our .net apps use odac

Is there a way of doing this upgrade without having to change all of our applications.

If we do need to change our code is there a good way to do it so we can install new client versions in the future without needing to tweak code.

Answer (score 2):

I've never had to change any code to update the oracle client.  Have you already tried it on your dev system and got errors?

Comment: yes it looks like .net is looking for a specific version OraOps10.dll and vb6 says a module is not found without any info on what its looking for.  I am now playing around with some test apps to learn any nuances that I can, any kicks in the pants, pointing me in the right direction would be great.

Comment: Looking at our .net code, it references Oracle.DataAccess specifically version 10.2.0.100 I'm guessing that is our mistake? Is there a way to reference oracle without specifying a version?